# in Mvc3 how could I disable validation on an input field when display:none?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

In Jquery you can disable validation for an input field client side (using ignore) , I need to do the same in MVC3

```
[DisplayName("Title")]
[Required]
public string Title { get; set; }

[DisplayName("OtherTitle")]
[Required]
public string OtherTitle{ get; set; }
```

in the .cshtml

```
    <div class="editor-label">
    <span>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Title)
    </span>
        @Html.DropDownListForNums(m => m.Title, new SelectList(new string[] { "Mr", "Ms", "Mrs", "Dr", "Professor", "OTHER" }, "Title"), "Title")
    </div>
    <div id="altTitle" class="editor-label">
       <span>
           @Html.LabelFor(x => x.OtherTitle)
       </span>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OtherTitle, new { @class = "othertitle" })
   </div>
```

How do I disable the validation on the input field for OtherTitle on the client side,  so when "Other" is selected in the dropdown I can turn it on again?

Thanks

Comment: hidden inputs are being ignored in jQuery validation by default... and the MVC client side validation is jQuery...

Comment: Apologies, I meant display:none not a hidden field. When display:none a [Required] field will be tested..this is what I'm trying to disable. Is this possible?